# Addition button in QGIS plugin form

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I want to create  PYQGIS plugin and for my task i need my QGIS GUI form to have one more button except to original button ok.

the additional button to do something and original button to do something else for my script.

first i add new button in `initGui` :

```
def initGui(self):
    icon_path = ':/plugins/twoobutton/icon.png'
    self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'twoobutton'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run1)
```

and after I create new `def run1`:

```
def run1(self):
    self.dlg.show()
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    if result:
        myvar = str(self.dlg.lineEdit_5.text())
        if myvar==1000:
            text1='hello'
            text2='world'
            self.dockWidget.dockWidgetContents.lineEdit.setText(str(text1))
            self.dockWidget.dockWidgetContents.lineEdit_2.setText(str(text2))
        pass
```

update :

```
class fff:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.dlg = fffDialog()
        self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run1)

        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'fff_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)


        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&ffffff')
        # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'fff')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'fff')
```

But if I click on pushbutton then don't show me anything.
How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Just put `self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run1)` in `__init__` not in `initGui()`.

```
def __init__(self, iface):
    # some code
    self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.run1)
```

Comment: if i put button in the `__init__` then show me no atrribute error ,why ?

Comment: AttributeError: nameplugin instance has no attribute 'dlg'

Comment: Now you know that connectiion is ok. Error is occuring when you try to execute this line: `self.dlg.show()` are you sure you want to do this there? What is that? You don't have any self.dlg object.

Comment: that error show me every time to start QGIS i have two buttons and 5 line edits what you mean self.dlg object ?

Comment: Are you sure thet you have something like `self.dlg = PluginDialog()` in your `__init__`?

Comment: not i put now you are correct now dont show me error but my code in run1 dont excetute if i push button :( i paste you my _init_

Comment: same here, any update on this?